# InAppPurchase restore- Non Renewing Subscription

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, restore, non-renewing-subscription

The Getting started with In-App Purchase on iOS and OS X (published February 3, 2014) document in "Restoring Previous Completed Purchases" specifies that non-renewing purchases must be transferred to other devices.
In-App Purchase Type: Non-Renewing Subscriptions
Restore Required?: Yes
Transaction Restoration Mechanism: Use iCloud or your own server to track purchases and allow user to restore purchased subscriptions to all iOS devices owned by a single user

Technical Note 4009, iTunes Store: About In-App Purchases (published July 29, 2014) in "Transfer an In-App Purchase" specifies that this is not allowed.
You can't sync or transfer non-renewing subscriptions and consumable In-App Purchase to another iOS device or Mac.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2):

Your app must allow the transfer/restore of in app purchase to other devices.  Your app will be rejected if not.  We have apps that transfers its purchases to other iOS devices

Answer (score 1):

Recently my app got rejected because it was having **Non-Renewing Subscription** with **restore** button. They rejected the app saying my app supports iOS6 to iOS 8 and validating a receipt was not possible in iOS6 so app should have an optional registration feature so a user can access subscription through other devices also.

I think removing support of iOS6 from the app will resolve my issue, so I am also looking for a suitable way because creating registration process is again a lengthy task.

[App Rejection on Restoring Non-Renewable subscription on iOS 6 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26965853/app-rejection-on-restoring-non-renewable-subscription-on-ios-6-app)