# App Rejection on Restoring Non-Renewable subscription on iOS 6 app

Tags: ios7, ios6, in-app-purchase, non-renewing-subscription

My app supports `iOS 6` to `iOS 8`. It has non-renewing subscription feature with a restore button and recently I got a rejection on this:

> We found that your app is using Receipt Validation found in `iOS 7+` to
>   restore `Non-Renewing Subscription`. However, since your Application
>   supports `iOS 6.0`, Non-Renewing Subscription cannot be restored in this
>   manner.
>
> It would be appropriate to remove this feature from you binary and
>   include an optional user registration feature, to deliver subscription
>   content to all of a user’s iOS devices. Such user registration must be
>   made optional, not required. We also recommend indicating that
>   registering is required to access the subscription content from their
>   other iOS devices - and providing a way to register later, if users
>   wish to have access to this content at a future time

They are saying my app supports `iOS 6` also and restoring a Non-Renewable Subscription is not possible with receipt validation on `iOS 6` so create optional registration feature so user can use same subscription on other devices also.

Is it ok if I remove support of `iOS 6` from my app rather than creating registration process? Will they approve if app will only install on `iOS 7` and above?

Comment: Probably they will approve your app, if you remove ios 6 support. Also you can ask directly their support, I did so several times, they will provide you with more trusted answer, you pay for it at least (yearly subscription fee).

Comment: Ok, I put a query on this. will wait for their reply 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described above, I configured my app to support minimum iOs 7 made it worked. That app is in Appstore now.

Thank you.
[image]